# d3.js applying color ranges not working with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am setting up a simple bar chart with d3.js and want each bar to have a different color depending on how big their value is. I have done this before but it doesn't seem to work with external JSON. I have my colors var setup like:

```
var maxConv = d3.max(data, function(d) {
 return d.conversion;
}); //This finds and returns the biggest value for 'conversion'

var convColors = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, maxConv]) // uses the maxConv var above as highest range point
                .range(['#ed5565','#da4453']);
```

However, when I apply this to each "rect" as a fill element it does not work (it shows in black):

```
d3.select('#bestConvertorBarChart').append('svg')
.selectAll('rect').data(data)
.enter()
.append('rect')
    .style('fill', convColors)
```

Am I doing something glaringly stupid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convColors` is being called with objects, not numbers. You need an accessor function like the one you used to compute the max value.

```
.style('fill', function (d) {
    return convColors(d.conversion);
});
```